# How to remove the new firebase onAuthStateChanged listener in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing firebase auth in a react web app with react-router.

A user signs in (at /signin) with either Facebook or Google using the popup sign in, then if successful I route to the main app (/). In the main app component I listen for an auth state change:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.authListener = this.authListener.bind(this);
    this.authListener();
  }
```

authListener listens for the auth change:

```
authListener() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('user changed..', user);
        this.setState({
          User: {
            displayName: user.displayName
          }
        });
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        browserHistory.push('/signin');
      }
    });
  }
```

Everything works fine, except when I sign out (and go back to /signin) and sign in again using facebook or google. Then I get an error saying:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component.

I suspect that the onAuthStateChanged listener from the now unmounted previous logged in state app is still running.

Is there a way to remove the onAuthStateChanged listener when the App component unmounts?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Any listeners that you have set up will also need to be torn down.

Your suspicions are very much on-spot.

You should use the [componentWillUnmount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#unmounting-componentwillunmount) lifecycle method to remove any leftover listeners that might pollute your app.

To clear up the listener, here's the relevant code:

Inside your `authListener` function you need to save a reference to the listener inside your component (it is returned to you as a result of calling `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`). It will be a hook that will un-reference the listener and remove it.

So instead of just calling it, save the returned value as such

```
this.fireBaseListener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged ...
```

And when your component un-mounts, use this code:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   this.fireBaseListener && this.fireBaseListener();
   this.authListener = undefined;
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to remove firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged? The old firebase had a .off() function

Comment: Yes, that's part of the old firebase. The new documentation is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged but I can't figure out how to use opt_completed ...

Comment: opt_completed as a callback function that will be called when the listener is removed. It is meant for clean-up logic upon the removal of your listener from firebase.

Comment: Updated my answer with logic relevant to your use-case. @user2248331

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you could explain what `this.fireBaseListener && this.fireBaseListener();` does. Thanks

Comment: @Justin calling `this.firebaseListener()` actually removes the listener. Since JS will evaluate from left to right it is basically the same as `if (this.firebaseListener) {this.firebaseListener()}`. Just making sure we don't call null as a function.

Answer (score 41):

I know I am late to the game, but here's a hooks based solution:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { // detaching the listener
        if (user) {
            // ...your code to handle authenticated users. 
        } else {
            // No user is signed in...code to handle unauthenticated users. 
        }
    });
    return () => unsubscribe(); // unsubscribing from the listener when the component is unmounting. 
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

@Justin because `onAuthStateChanged` returns function so you can use it to clear the listener...
`this.fireBaseListener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`

docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

> Returns non-null firebase.Promise containing non-null Array of string

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firebase 9 you should pay attention to the way you call the function
`onAuthStateChanged`

First way

```
import firebaseApp from 'path/to/your/firebase/app';
// you will need to do 
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            // user is signed in
        } else {
            // user is signed out
        }
    });
    
    // unsubscribing from the listener when the component is unmounting.
    return unsubscribe;
}, [])
```

Second way

```
import firebaseApp from 'path/to/your/firebase/app';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);


useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        ...
    });
    
    // unsubscribing from the listener when the component is unmounting.
    return unsubscribe;
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking `onAuthStateChanged()` function inside `componentDidMount()` you can check subscription's like this.

```
componentWillMount() {
    //following line will help you to setState() but not required
    let set =  this  

    //this is our trick
    this.unsubscribe  = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (!user) {
            //navigate to guest stack
            //actually im using react-navigation
            set.props.navigation.navigate('Guest'); 
        } else {
            //set current user to state 
            set.setState({
                user: user,
                loading: false
            })
        }
    });
}

//What you have to do next is unsubscribe ;) 
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
}
```