# onClick called repeatedly (not supposed to) when component re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component which is a form. When user clicks on the send/submit button, a function is called to handle data saving and do some other tasks.

The issue is after the user clicks the button, the component seems to re-render several times (most likely because the external props it receives from other components got updated). That in itself is not a problem.

However, when the component updates, the `onClick` function gets called again, even though user hasn't clicked on the button again.

This is the part I don't understand. Why does the `onClick` function gets triggered when the component updates? And how can I prevent this from happening?

I don't want to stop the component from updating after user clicks on the button. Because the user may want to change something in the form and send it again.

The component in a nutshell looks like the following:

```js
class Form extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
    }
  }
  
  save() {
    // do something
    // and something else...
    alert('data saved!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => {this.setState({input: e.target.value})}}
            value={this.state.input}
          />
        </div>
        <div onClick={this.save.bind(this)}>
         <span>submit</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

*** UPDATE ***
I think I figured out what went wrong.

What I didn't mention in the post above is that there's a firebase auth event listener inside of the `save` function, to make sure user is authenticated. It looked like this:

```
save () {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
              if (user) {
                 // do something
                 // and something else
                 alert('data saved');
              } else {
                // do something else
              }
  });
}
```

That event listener for some reason gets triggered multiple times (it shouldn't) after user submitting. The bottomline is his is not related to component updating.

I now have assigned a value to the event listener and set it to null after it's triggered once, like so:

```
save () {
  const that = this;
  this.firebaseListener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
              if (user) {
                 // do something
                 // and something else
                 alert('data saved');
                 that.firebaseListener = null; 
              } else {
                // do something else
              }
  });
  this.firebaseListener && this.firebaseListener();
}
```

This seems to be working so far...

Comment: Have you tried using preventDefault() ?

Comment: are you using `save` function somewhere else or it is just attached to `onClick` on the `div`?

Comment: @margaretkru it's only attached to this particular `onClick`.

Comment: your code works fine! I think you'are calling save in another function/action. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/98160/

Comment: I don’t see any reason for this function to be called again after rerender. Could you post the code where you use your Form component and some context around it?

Comment: @margaretkru thanks for looking into this. I think I figured it out. See updated post.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your firebase woes, see this answer: [How to remove the new firebase onAuthStateChanged listener in react](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38038343/2479481)

Sounds like you're on the right track, but you might want to set the auth listener up earlier in the lifecycle. That way, your users know they're already logged in before they try to save the form. Depends on your use case, though.

Don't use arrow functions or `bind` in `render`. Do this instead:

```
class Form extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.save = this.save.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({input: e.target.value});
  }

  save() {
    // do something
    // and something else...
    alert('data saved!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.input}
          />
        </div>
        <div onClick={this.save}>
          <span>submit</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This change should fix the re-rendering of your form. This is because the function changes each time render is called, which can trigger re-renders.