# Fetching User Data from user collection on login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on an application with firebase initialized on the client side.  When a user logs in via firebase, I want to fetch the user's data from the firestore.  I am currently doing so within the `onAuthStateChanged` listener and successfully fetching the user.  I am wondering if this is the best way to go about fetching the user data.  My code is as follows:

```js
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null)
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('state unknown')
    setAuthState(false)
    auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return
      }
      const sourceRef = firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .where('userId', '==', user.uid)
      sourceRef
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          if (snapshot.empty) {
            console.log('user not found')
          } else {
            let data = {}
            snapshot.forEach(item => (data = item.data()))
            console.log(data)
            setCurrentUser(data)
            setAuthState(true)
          }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.code))
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, authState }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

my main concern is that the user's data will be fetched every time the application is refreshed. Any suggestions or best practices on the matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `onAuthStateChanged` returns [firebase.Unsubscribe](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) function for the observer that you need to call to unsubscribe to the listener. Check [remove firebase onauthstatechanged listener in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038343/how-to-remove-the-new-firebase-onauthstatechanged-listener-in-react)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO your approach using context API and auth observer is already good, with only minor issues:

- you should unsubscribe your observers as mentioned by Awran5
- you could observe user data instead of fetching it only once
- you could separate your contexts for readability and performance
- you could create your documents in collection users with the id of the owner, so you can directly access `collection("users").doc(authUser.uid)` instead of doing a query

Here is how I would modify your example, not sure if it is the best way, I am awaiting on others comments:

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext();

function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [authUser, setAuthUser] = React.useState(undefined);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => setAuthUser(user));
    }, []);

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={authUser}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}
```

```
const UserDataContext = React.createContext();

function UserDataProvider({ children }) {
    const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState(null);
    const authUser = React.useContext(AuthContext);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!authUser) return;
        const query = firebase.firestore().collection("/users").where("userId", "==", authUser.uid);
        return query.onSnapshot(snapshot => setUserData(snapshot.empty ? null : snapshot.docs[0].data()));
    }, [authUser]);

    return <UserDataContext.Provider value={userData}>{children}</UserDataContext.Provider>;
}
```

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <UserDataProvider>
                {/* ... other components */}
                <MyComponent />
            </UserDataProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}
```

```
function MyComponent() {
    const authUser = React.useContext(AuthContext);
    const userData = React.useContext(UserDataContext);
    if (authUser === undefined) return <div>loading user authentication...</div>;
    if (authUser === null) return <div>logged out</div>;
    return <div>User data: {JSON.stringify(userData)}</div>;
}
```

Your components will still be re-rendered on auth state change, or on user data change, but only as needed.

Comment: when you say observe user data are you saying the data would update if there were changes to the user table?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It is one of my favorite feature: with Firestore you can either observe your data to receive the new values when they change, or fetch the data once.

Comment: very cool! prefer this to having to constantly refetch etc.  Do you know billing implications of observing changes as opposed to fetching as needed

Comment: The pricing implications for listening to real time updates is explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens